# Change GWT SubMenu Popup Location

Tags: gwt, menubar

In menubar, normally submenu gets displayed on the right hand side. I want to change to Left hand side. Can anyone please let me know, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popup location of Sub menu is defined by CSS elements at rendering based on position of menu items.

Looking Via Firebug On Main Menu It produced:

```
element.style {
    clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
    left: 337px; // Change this to left:35px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 319px;
    visibility: visible;
}

// This is main CSS for popup
.gwt-MenuBarPopup{
}
```

So, Give it a try by using `setStyleName("css goes here")` from code

Comment: Hey Hardik,Thanks for ur prompt reply. I have done the same and achieve that.

Comment: You can indeed do addStyleName on the menu group INSIDE the popup, but not on the one that is actually ".gwt-MenuBarPopup". Since a menubar popup isn't created until needed in response to user actions (hover, click), you can't even style the popup by its index. Nor by its parent, since its DOM container has no parent at all, in fact. I've yet to find a way to make one popup position itself differently than another (say, last one  on right needing to popup to LEFT of originating item). Seems like a major oversight to have no alignment abilities for the MenuBar class.

Answer (score 0):

I again advise you to override the default styles GWT:) I used this method on my project when I had to change some standard view of GWT-elements.

Comment: I know that it can be done through that only. But will you please tell me which styles i do need to override?

Comment: I opened a sample menubar in firebug and saw that all of MenuBar's items has CSS-style class "gwt-MenuItem". Also each item has its identifier, such as "gwt-uid-1", "gwt-uid-2" and so on. If you want to override the default style of element, then connect to the host page, your CSS file and write new properties for needsclasses and IDs. I advise you to connect the CSS file to the end of the section head of the host page after connecting GWT scripts, otherwise change can not override default styles. If you want, I can describe the points as I did it)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement a solution by changing the css as well. Perhaps this isn't the most elegant way, but it works. Using a little help from GwtQuery's closest() method, here is a short example.

```
        menuBar.addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {            
        @Override
        public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
            if(event.isAttached()){
                Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {                       
                    @Override
                    public void execute() {
                        Element e = $(menuBar).closest(".gwt-MenuBarPopup").get(0);
                        e.getStyle().setLeft(parentMenuBar.getAbsoluteLeft()-menuBar.getOffsetWidth() , Unit.PX);
                    }
                });                 
            }
        }
    });
```

So the idea being when the child sub menu is attached, you want to change the css. I use a deferred command so that it will change the css after GWT's default MenuBar implementation sets it.
This line, "$(menuBar).closest(".gwt-MenuBarPopup").get(0);" will search up the DOM tree until it finds the element with the class .gwt-MenuBarPopup, which is the one you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is somewhat of a hybrid of those posted so far here, but I think it is cleaner/simpler than any of them.

1. Each vertical subMenu is itself a `MenuBar`, added as an item to the top-level 
   `MenuBar`.  For whichever subMenu you want to drop to the left instead of the right, add a style class name to it using `.addStyleName("myLeftDropDownStyleName")` on that `MenuBar` Widget.
2. Define the selector rule for that style like this (these are the minimum attributes that were necessary for me to get the left dropping):

   `.myLeftDropDownStyleName{
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
    }`

[Absolute](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) positions relative to the first parent element with a position other than static; for my case at least, that parent position seemed to be horizontal place where the dropdown otherwise has its left edge without this solution. I wouldn't be suprised if [Relative](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) position might work better in some other people's cases.

The Right offset of 0px tells the absolute position's right to be at that horizontal place I mentioned above.  And of course the pixel size can be > 0 to push further to the left by that much, or even < 0 to pull it back to the right by that much.

This works perfectly for me, is simple & clean, and does not force *all* of your MenuBars to have this style (as I think would be the case if you overrode one of the GWT MenuBar styles themself).